# How to set default screen that will be showed while other pages are reloading? ReactRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-functional-component

I need to entertain user a bit while he's waiting the pages reloading/routing from one page to another. My app is using `ReactRouter` and (obviously) `React`. How to set such a page that will be a placeholder while the target page is reloading. Say, rotating logo or something like that! Is it possible to do it with React? And how will that "placeholder while others are loading page" be developed so that it loads fast? Please help me making me out how to do it!

```jsx
function App() {
  return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          {
            <>
              <Route exact path="/politics-we">
                <>
                  <Global>{device === "mobile" ? <WeMob /> : <We />}</Global>
                </>
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/politics-our">
                <>
                  <Global>{device === "mobile" ? <OurMob /> : <Our />}</Global>
                </>
              </Route>

              <Route path="/mzs-popular">
                <>
                  <Global>
                    {device === "mobile" ? <MZsPopularMob /> : <MZsPopular />}
                  </Global>
                </>
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/meme/write">
                <>
                  <Global>
                    {device === "mobile" ? (
                      <WritePostMob group="memecreate" title="Meme" />
                    ) : (
                      <WritePost group="memecreate" title="Meme" />
                    )}
                  </Global>
                </>
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/mzs/write">
                <>
                  <Global>
                    {device === "mobile" ? (
                      <WritePostMob group="mzsgeneralcreate" title="MZs" />
                    ) : (
                      <WritePost group="mzsgeneralcreate" title="MZs" />
                    )}
                  </Global>
                </>
              </Route>
              <Route path="/terms">
                <>
                  <Global>
                    <Terms />
                  </Global>
                </>
              </Route>
              <Route path="/info">
                <>
                  <Global>
                    <Info />
                  </Global>
                </>
              </Route>
              <Route path="/user-page">
                <>
                  <Global>
                    <UserPage />
                  </Global>
                </>
              </Route>
              <Route path="/notice">
                <>
                  <Global>
                    <Notice />
                  </Global>
                </>
              </Route>
              <Route path="/policy">
                <>
                  <Global>
                    <Policy />
                  </Global>
                </>
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/">
                <>
                  <Global>
                    {device === "mobile" ? <BeforeSignInMob /> : <SignIn />}
                  </Global>
                </>
              </Route>
            </>
          }
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can use something like `<Suspense fallback={<DefaultLoader />}>...Your Routing Code</Suspense>` and the DefaultLoader will be the component you want to show as loader.

Comment: Thank you, Amit! I'll try that now!

Comment: More from here
https://css-tricks.com/react-suspense-in-practice/

Comment: Amit, it's working, please post you comment as an answer!

Comment: The purpose is to help, not to earn points. If it has to be big enough to put in answer mode, maybe I could have done that.